# Connecting to Azure CosmosDb from .NET 4.7.2

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

I'm trying to connect to an Azure Cosmos DB from old .NET 4.7.2 (I can't migrate to .NET CORE because of the client)
and sometimes it's working sometimes doesn't. I receive an error "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UserAgentContainer' threw an exception".
Do you know if I can use CosmosDB with this version of .NET?

I used "Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.34", but doesn't work.
I used also "Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core v 2.20.0"

Code with Microsoft.Azure.Cosmos v3.34:

```
public class CosmosService
    {
        private readonly CosmosClient _client;
        private readonly DocumentClient client;
        private string databaseId = "xxx";
        private string accountContainer = "Accounts";
        private string contactTable = "Contacts";
        private string companyTable = "Companies";

        private Container container
        {
            get => _client.GetDatabase(databaseId).GetContainer(accountContainer);
        }

        //private CosmosClientOptions clientOptions = new CosmosClientOptions()
        //{
        //    SerializerOptions = new CosmosSerializationOptions() { PropertyNamingPolicy = CosmosPropertyNamingPolicy.CamelCase },
        //};

        public CosmosService()
        {
            //just one initialization at a time
            _client = new CosmosClient(connectionString: connectionStrings, clientOptions);
            _client = new CosmosClient(accountEndpoint: "endpoint", authKeyOrResourceToken: "primarykey");
        }
}
```

Code with Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core v 2.20.0:

```
public CosmosService()
        {
            using (var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("endpoint"), "primaryKey"))
            {
                IDocumentQuery<AccountModel> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<AccountModel>(
                  UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(databaseId, accountContainer),
                    new FeedOptions { MaxItemCount = -1 }).AsDocumentQuery();
            }
        }
```

Both of them throw: "The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UserAgentContainer"

I added an image with the exception from VS
[QuickWatch Exception](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cGPE7.png)

Error Mesagge:
The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UserAgentContainer' threw an exception.
Stacktrace:

> at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.UserAgentContainer..ctor()    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy..ctor()    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.ConnectionPolicy.get_Default()    at
> Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient.Initialize(Uri
> serviceEndpoint, ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, Nullable`1 desiredConsistencyLevel, HttpMessageHandler handler, ISessionContainer sessionContainer, IStoreClientFactory storeClientFactory)    at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient..ctor(Uri serviceEndpoint, String authKeyOrResourceToken, EventHandler`1
> sendingRequestEventArgs, ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, Nullable`1 desiredConsistencyLevel, JsonSerializerSettings serializerSettings, ApiType apitype, EventHandler`1 receivedResponseEventArgs,
> HttpMessageHandler handler, ISessionContainer sessionContainer,
> IStoreClientFactory storeClientFactory, SecureString secureAuthKey,
> Func`2 transportClientHandlerFactory)    at Microsoft.Azure.Documents.Client.DocumentClient..ctor(Uri serviceEndpoint, String authKeyOrResourceToken, ConnectionPolicy connectionPolicy, Nullable`1 desiredConsistencyLevel)    at
> HighRoad.CosmosDb.CosmosService..ctor() in
> C:\Work\05_PlusConnector\CosmosDb\CosmosService.cs:line 36    at
> PlusConnector.main.Main(String[] args) in
> C:\Work\05_PlusConnector\PlusConnector\code\Main.cs:line 35

Comment: Can you please share the full exception with stack trace? Also, you shouldn't use `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.Core` but `Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB` for .NET FX.

Comment: I added an image in the first post

Comment: The InnerException says "Thread is being aborted". Are you disposing the client instance through `using`? Are you following the [best practices](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/nosql/best-practice-dotnet) and keeping a singleton client?

Answer (score 0):

The solution for my problem was to uninstall all libraries related to cosmos and used just Microsoft.Azure.DocumentDB.

```
var client = new DocumentClient(new Uri("databaseId"), "primaryKey", camelCaseOptions);

public async Task<AccountModel> GetAccountItem(string id, string partitionKey)
        {                
            string sqlQuery = "SELECT * FROM Accounts a WHERE a.id = @Id";
            var querySpec = new SqlQuerySpec(sqlQuery, new SqlParameterCollection() { new SqlParameter("@Id", id) });

            IDocumentQuery<AccountModel> query = client.CreateDocumentQuery<AccountModel>(accountUri, querySpec).AsDocumentQuery();

            FeedResponse<AccountModel> result = await query.ExecuteNextAsync<AccountModel>();

            var account = result.First();

            return account;
        }
```